# Visual Studio Community installation - asks to restart, does not appear after

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, installation

I tried to install VS Community 2013 with Update 4; after download (with chrome - should that be the problem?) and the screen with "Acquiring" and "Applying" was entirely finished, it told me to restart.

After I did this, there was no sign of the installation being continued; I don't see a folder "Community" anywhere. There is a new folder "MS VS 12.0" in what I do not see any applications related to "community".
What should I do?
Download again with IE? ...